# Overriding generic function using sub-class type parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following interface in kotlin, not modifiable because it's defined in a third party library. And I would like to override the generic method using a type parameter of the subclass:

```
interface Factory {
    fun <T> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T
}


// The naive solution doesn't compile :  "Class is not abstract and does not implement abstract member":
class ConcreteFactory1 <T> (val creator: () -> T) : Factory {
    override fun create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return creator()
    }
}


// If we introduce a second type parameter, it compiles, but generates a "Unchecked Cast" warning:
class ConcreteFactory2 <T> (val creator: () -> T) : Factory {
    override fun <T2> create(modelClass: Class<T2>): T2 {
        return creator() as T2
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without compilation warning ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.
That interface requires that you're able to handle any possbile `Class<T>` and your implementation doesn't.

So the question is what do you want to do when `create` is called with a type which is not the one your `ConcreteFactory2` can create?

If the only thing you want is not to see the unchecked cast you can do this:

```kotlin
class ConcreteFactory2 <T> (val creator: () -> T) : Factory {
    override fun <T2> create(modelClass: Class<T2>): T2 {
        return creator() as? T2 ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unsupported type")
    }
}
```

But whether that is an acceptable implementation of that interface really depends on how is that used.

Comment: Warning is still there with this solution  ```Unchecked cast: T to T2```

Comment: Since the type isn't reified, I don't think a safe cast operator will work. You'll just get a ClassCastException when it returns instead of the more informative IllegalArgumentException. But this approach could work if you have a KClass property in the constructor so the type can be reified and checked for real.

Comment: I'm wrong. That would only reify T, not T2. There's no way to reify T2, so you can't safely cast it.

Comment: whoops, sorry didn't try that out